# Relative path issue when running programs with Task Scheduler

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to use Windows 10 Task Scheduler to run an MFC app after login.

No problem as far as execution is concerned, but I am facing a problem in reading files using relative paths.

Is there something different about Task Scheduler execution than normal execution?

Or, is there another solution to set the startup path in the `Eshell.exe` shell?

For example:

```cpp
CIniFile OptionINI(_T(".\\userOption.ini"), 1024);
// File not found

CIniFile OptionINI(_T("c:\\my\\userOption.ini"), 1024);
// File found successfully
```

Comment: What is "sw"???

Comment: When you configure a task in Task Scheduler, you get to specify the initial working directory, via the "Start in" box.

Comment: Relative paths are the work of Satan. Avoid using them. Read a full path out of a fixed-location resource like the registry that's set during installation or build a structure relative to the executable location, [query windows to get the location of the executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea), and append your path to the executable's path

Comment: Both the "Start in" setting and the "get the location of the executable, and append your path to the executable's path" workaround solved the problem.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: And this is exactly why you should not rely on relative paths in your code. They are dependent on the calling process's Current Working Directory, which is dynamic and can change at any time, and can be influenced by external forces that you may or may not have control over. Always use absolute paths in your code. If you must use a relative path, then you should first combine it with an absolute base path that is known to your code, and then use the result as needed.